# How to request device token on iphone

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification

I am able to use the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken callback method to get the device token of my iphone when subscribing to push notifications.  My question is how can I get this token again a later time?  When a user subscribes to something in my application, I want to send the device token and the id of the item they are subscribing to...but I can't figure out where to get the device token from.  I tried using the uniqueIdentifer from the UIDevice class but this value is different than what the original token was.  I supposed I could call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes each time my app starts to produce the token.  But if I do that, I'm not sure how I can access this value from a different class (my didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken callback is located in the main application delegate).  Thanks for any help for an objective C newbie!

Answer (score 5):

I would set a property in your appDelegate that can be accessed from anywhere, and set it to the device token.

```
// .h
@interface SomeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString * dToken;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dToken;

// .m
@implementation SomeAppDelegate;
@synthesize dToken;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString * token = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self setDToken:token];
    [token release];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [dToken release]
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You can then access that token anywhere by using:

```
NSString * token = [(SomeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dToken];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am able to set the variable in the delegate and retrieve it using [self deviceId] from within the delegate class.  However, when I try to retrieve it using the code you provided it does not work.  The application compiles, but when it gets to that line I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error with no other information.  I am having a lot of trouble with the objective c syntax and the lack of a reasonable error message is making this really hard to figure out.  Any help would be grately appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work.  I'm not sure why but when I did not release the token String it worked fine without any issue.